# Error with systemd-sysv libnss-systemd:amd64 libpulsedsp:amd64 network-manager gdm3 network-manager-gnome

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 via bootable USB, now I have graphic problems, such as:

- blue desktop
- only some programs are accessible

and when I try to install the Nvidia driver I am prompted to use

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

then I get a set of errors:
(In german: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von)

```
libnss-systemd:amd64 
libpulsedsp:amd64 
network-manager 
gdm3 
network-manager-gnome
```

Can someone help me? What would be next steps?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by

`sudo apt-get update` and

`sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`.

Thus I could install the nvidia-driver (460).